# Shorten an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have a very simple question. Is there a built in method to shorten strings? If not can someone provide an example of doing that in **ObjC**?

For example:

> ThisIsAVeryLongString

should become

> ThisIsAV...

It needs to check if the string is over a certain amount of characters and if it is shorten it.

Comment: If you're doing this to display a truncated string, the just be aware that many UI elements will do this for you already (`NSTextField`, `UILabel`, and many others).  Are you *sure* you need to do this manually?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward...

```
NSString *originalString = @"SomethingVeryLong";
int newLength = 9;
if (originalString.length > newLength)
    NSString *shortString = [originalString substringToIndex:newLength];
```